# Are children eligible for British citizenship when one of the parents acquire settled status?

Tags: uk-citizens, uk-citizenship

I am getting settled status (ILR) this August. My daughter is Indian, and was born three years ago in the UK. Is she eligible for British citizenship once I acquire ILR? Or is she eligible only at the same time as myself, when I apply for citizenship a year later?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "settled status" means that you're participating in the EU settlement scheme.  The term that encompasses all the various statuses that lead to children being UK citizens from birth, including citizenship, ILR, settled status, and some others, is "settled in the UK."  It's confusing.  Whether you're truly getting settled status or another form of ILR doesn't affect the answer to this question (aside from the question of which bullet point to call attention to), but it might have other implications for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your daughter can register as a British citizen when you acquire ILR: From https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-born-uk/under-18 (emphasis added):

> ## If you're under 18
>
> You can register to become a British citizen if one of your parents considered the UK as their home and did any of the following after you were born:
>
> - became a British citizen
> - **got indefinite leave to remain in the UK**
> - got ‘settled status’ (also known as ‘indefinite leave to remain under the EU Settlement Scheme’)
> - got indefinite leave to enter the UK
> - got permanent residence status
>
> You must have been born in the UK and be under 18 when you apply.

If for some reason you don't acquire ILR as you expect to do, your daughter can register as a British citizen after she turns 10 (subject to a condition limiting her absences from the UK to less than 90 days each year).  Details are shown at https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-born-uk/uk-until-10

The fee is heavy, currently £1013, but it seems to be the same for both routes.